# using next in a list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, heap, heapsort

I'm trying to do something quite simple, which I have probably overcomplicated:

This is the problem:

Let's say you are living in a controlled economy where there is a baker in town, and every day he bakes a certain number of loaves of bread. The people in the town queue up to buy a loaf of bread (you can only buy one loaf).

There are more people in the queue than loaves of bread available. Everyone in the queue gets a ticket for the number that they are in the queue to prevent queue jumping, but they are the same order every single day (keeping it simple). The bread is ready at different times each day, and some people in the queue need to be at work, if the bread isn't ready before they have to leave for work, they leave the queue and the next person in line takes their place. But they still have their original queue ticket. The values in the original list are the number of hours before the person in the queue has to leave for work

I want to know what is the number on the last ticket given to the baker each day before he runs out of loaves of bread.

I can get my existing code to work for relatively small numbers of people, but if there are millions of people, lots of days (planned economies plan for 5 years ahead), you get the picture.

```
def BakerQueue(loaves, people, bake_time):
    got_some_bread = []
    for b in bake_time:
        counter = 0
        for p in range(len(people)):
            if people[p] >= b:
                counter += 1
                if counter == loaves:
                    got_some_bread.append(p + 1)
                    counter = 0
                    break
                elif p == len(people) - 1:
                    got_some_bread.append(0)
                    break
            elif counter < loaves and p == len(people) - 1:
                got_some_bread.append(0)
                counter = 0
    return got_some_bread
```

You can use this to run the code: in this example, there are 3, 18 people in the list, and different bake times for each of the days in a week, so on the first day, ticket 1, 2, 3 get loaves, on the second day 2,3,4 get loaves, on the third day, 7, 9 and 15 get loaves. I only care about who gets the last loaf on each day which is what the function is returning.

```
BakerQueue(3, [1, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 6, 1, 9, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 6, 9, 4, 5, 8],[1, 2, 5, 4, 5, 4, 7])
```

This will return as expected

```
[3, 4, 15, 7, 15, 7, 19]
```

Essentially, I want to prioritise the index level of a list and pop any values that are greater than another value

I have a list: `my_list = [1, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 6]` and I want to maintain it's index priority so I have enumerated both index and value into a new list:

`my_list_of_tuples = [(i, j) for i, j in enumerate(my_list)]`

This gives me: `[(0, 1), (1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 3), (4, 1), (5, 2), (6, 6)]`

I then convert this into a heap

`heapq.heapify(my_list_of_tuples)`

Now, I want to check whether the value at the top of the heap is greater than the iterated constant in a separate list I want to iterate through. If it is, I want to pop it from the heap `heapq.heappop(my_list_of_tuples)`

The code I thought to do this is as follows, but it doesn't work, so probably doesn't work, but how can I access the value at the top of the heap, I thought of writing something like this:

```
    counter = 0
    while counter <= static_constant:
        if next([v[1] for v in my_list_of_tuples]) < iterated_constant:
            heapq.heappop(my_list_of_tuples)
        else:
            counter += 1
```

Hoping to get some help on how to deal with the list comprehension generator. Thank you

Comment: Could you give an example how the result *should* look like? 'pop any values that are greater than another value' is quite vague...

Comment: if for example, the iterated_constant is 3, then if the value at the top of the heap is < 3, pop it off. Once my counter has been reached, i want the index value of the value at the top of the heap

Comment: I try to understand what you are saying, but I really don't. Please provide a simple example instead of a convoluted description that references variables like iterated_constant that are unknown where they come from.
After thinking about it a lot I think I understand that the list, the static_constant and the iterated_constant are given as input parameters of this algorithm, but that really wasn't clear from your description. Nonetheless, I still don't understand what they are supposed to do.

Comment: Also, I'm quite confident that this is an xy problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). I don't think using next in a list comprehension is actually what's wrong with your algorithm, as next with a list comprehension doesn't make much sense imo. I think the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: I have updated the question with a more concrete example of the problem, apologises for being too generic

Comment: Thanks for that, but I actually meant a more concrete example than a textual description, like a test: for a specific list and specific constants, what is the expected outcome?
I don't understand the 'they go to work before the bread is ready' part, will they come back? Will they still pick up their bread? How is determined when they have to 'go to work'? How does that reflect in your numbers?

Comment: I'm not quite following how this relates to ``next`` and list comprehensions. Your descriptions talks about tuples and lists, which are easily indexable. ``next([v[1] for v in my_list_of_tuples])`` should just be ``my_list_of_tuples[0][1]``, for example. If instead you want something like fast-forwarding an iterator by a condition, ``itertools.dropwhile`` might be what you are looking for.

Comment: "Now, I want to check whether the value at the top of the heap is greater than the iterated constant in a separate list I want to iterate through" Where is that list. Please try to provide us with: All Inputs, current (faulty) output and your expected output for that example.

Comment: "I then convert this into a heap" - prioritized by index or by value? If by index, you could just iterate through the list instead ...

Comment: @MisterMiyagi that's exactly why I strongly suspect this to be an XY-problem

Comment: I've updated with the code i wrote that works for small numbers of people, but I want it to scale.

Comment: Note that if you already have working code, [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) may be more appropriate than [SO]. Please be mindful of their policies and read their how-to-ask whether your question actually applies, and how it should be presented.

Comment: Thx @MisterMiyagi I will try there

Comment: @Finomnis I've added some extra info to the question so you can call the function and see what it does

Comment: So, the code you provided (the BakerQueue) is the code you currently have, and you try to speed it up? Is that what happens? Because what you say is still very confusing. And I still don't see a simple: input -> method -> expected output anywhere. I will try to understand your problem again, but I can't promise anything.

Comment: Well that escalated quickly.

Comment: I also responded on CodeReview, if you want we can close this topic here and continue there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understood your problem.

### Problem description

**Given:**

- `num_items` - the number of available items
- `targets` - a list of potential targets, each having a value
- `threshold` - a cutoff limit

**Task:**

- Choose the first `num_items` elements of `targets`, whose values are above or equal to `threshold`.
- Return the array index of the last chosen element from `targets` (starting with `1`), or `0` if not enough targets are available. (Odd decision, I would have gone with indices starting at `0` and return `len(targets)` if none found, but fine)
- Optimize for speed. `targets` and `num_items` are identical every time, `threshold` is the only value that changes.

---

### Example

```
num_items = 3
targets = [5,3,4,1,3,3,7,4]
threshold = 4
```

Chosen targets would be the ones at the positions `[0,2,6]`, with the values `[5,4,7]`, as those are the first `3` values that are above or equal to `threshold`. We only search the index of the last one, which in this case would be `6`.

---

### Approach

Your original idea was to iterate through all the people which is very fast if the threshold is very low, but becomes really slow if the threshold is higher, as we need to iterate through all the people until we find a candidate.

I rewrote your original idea to iterate through all of them, as I wasn't able to understand your code:

```py
def choose_first_n(num_items, targets, threshold):
    for target_id, target in enumerate(targets):
        if target >= threshold:
            num_items -= 1
            if num_items == 0:
                return target_id + 1
    return 0

def baker_queue(num_loaves_per_day, people_max_waiting_time, required_baking_times):
    results = []
    for today_baking_time in required_baking_times:
        results.append(choose_first_n(num_loaves_per_day, people_max_waiting_time, today_baking_time))
    return results

print(baker_queue(3,
                  [1, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 6, 1, 9, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 6, 9, 4, 5, 8],
                  [1, 2, 5, 4, 5, 4, 7]))
# Returns: [3, 4, 15, 7, 15, 7, 19], as in the original code.
# Also, please provide expected return values in future, like I did here.
```

Using a heap is an interesting idea, but I don't think we benefit from that in any way. Heaps are only really fast for item removal/insertion, which we don't do. We just iterate over them.

The fastest way that I could think of is to pre-process the `threshold` list into something more efficient, as if, create an 'index' of the last item.

*Demonstration:*
We use our previous code, and look at the results based on the threshold value:

```
def choose_first_n(num_items, targets, threshold):
    for target_id, target in enumerate(targets):
        if target >= threshold:
            num_items -= 1
            if num_items == 0:
                return target_id + 1
    return 0

targets = [1, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 6, 1, 9, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 6, 9, 4, 5, 8]
num_items = 3

for threshold in range (10):
    result = choose_first_n(num_items, targets, threshold)
    print(f"Threshold: {threshold}, Result: {result}")
```

```
Threshold: 0, Result: 3
Threshold: 1, Result: 3
Threshold: 2, Result: 4
Threshold: 3, Result: 4
Threshold: 4, Result: 7
Threshold: 5, Result: 15
Threshold: 6, Result: 15
Threshold: 7, Result: 19
Threshold: 8, Result: 19
Threshold: 9, Result: 0
```

You can see that if the threshold goes up, the result goes up. There is a linear steadily increasing relationship between the threshold and the result.

If we can compute the values at which the result changes, we can compute the result directly via a divide-and-conquer search, which is a LOT faster than iterating through the list. (`O(logn)` instead of `O(n)`, in case you are familiar with Big-O notation)

One thing to note here is that the last result is `0`, which brakes that scheme. That is the reason why it is benefitial to let the indices start with `0` instead of `1`, and have the 'error' case be `len(targets)` instead of `0`.

### Preprocessing

The hardest thing is the preprocessing to get to that mapping.

Let's look at it from the other way round.

For the sake of simplicity, let's say num_items is 3, and we have 10 targets.
Will the chosen targets be within the first 5 targets?

The answer is: yes, IF at least 3 of the first 5 targets are above or equal to the threshold. Or in other words, the 3rd largest number in the list is the deciding factor. If the threshold is above the 3rd largest number, the chosen targets will not only be within the first 5 targets.

Therefore, for all items, we need to compute the 3rd largest number. Funnily, this is actually where a heap WILL come in handy ;)

### Implementation

```
import heapq
import bisect

def preprocess(targets, num_items):
    # our heap, will contain the first num_items smallest targets
    largest_targets_heap = []

    # Our first preprocessing result, will contain the
    # third large number between the first item and the current item,
    # for every item.
    third_largest_number_per_target = []

    # Compute the third largest previous value for every target
    for target in targets:
        heapq.heappush(largest_targets_heap, target)
        if len(largest_targets_heap) > num_items:
            heapq.heappop(largest_targets_heap)

        current_third_largest = largest_targets_heap[0]
        third_largest_number_per_target.append(current_third_largest)

    # We now have the third largest number for every target.
    # Now, consolidate that data into a lookup table, to prevent duplication.
    # Therefore, find the first occurrence of every number
    lookup_table_indices = []
    lookup_table_values = []
    current_value = third_largest_number_per_target[num_items - 1]

    # Push the (num_items-1)th value to account for the fact our heap wasn't filled up until the
    # first num_items were processed
    lookup_table_indices.append(num_items - 1)
    lookup_table_values.append(current_value)

    # Fill the rest of the lookup table
    for index, value in enumerate(third_largest_number_per_target):
        if index < num_items - 1:
            continue
        if value != current_value:
            lookup_table_indices.append(index)
            lookup_table_values.append(value)
            current_value = value

    # The lookup table we have, consisting of values, indices, a minimum and a maximum value
    lookup_table = (lookup_table_values, lookup_table_indices, num_items, len(targets))

    return lookup_table

def choose_first_n_preprocessed(lookup_table, threshold):
    (lookup_table_values, lookup_table_indices, min_value, max_value) = lookup_table

    # We need to find the first (value,index) pair in lookup table where value is larger or equal to threshold
    # We do this by using bisect, which is really fast. This is only possible because of our preprocessing.
    position = bisect.bisect_left(lookup_table_values, threshold)

    # If we didn't find a result in the preprocessed table, we return the max value, to indicate that the
    # threshold ist too high.
    if position >= len(lookup_table_indices):
        return max_value

    # Read the result from the table of incides
    value = lookup_table_indices[position]
    return value

def baker_queue(num_loaves_per_day, people_max_waiting_time, required_baking_times):
    # Create the preprocessed lookup table
    lookup_table = preprocess(people_max_waiting_time, num_loaves_per_day)

    # For every day, compute the result
    results = []
    for today_baking_time in required_baking_times:
        # Use our fast lookup based algorithm now
        result = choose_first_n_preprocessed(lookup_table, today_baking_time)
        
        # Convert indices back to starting with 1, and 0 in error case, as
        # the original format was
        if result == len(people_max_waiting_time):
            results.append(0)
        else:
            results.append(result+1)
    return results

print(baker_queue(3,
                  [1, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 6, 1, 9, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 6, 9, 4, 5, 8],
                  [1, 2, 5, 4, 5, 4, 7]))
# [3, 4, 15, 7, 15, 7, 19]
```

### Theoretical Analysis

This should now be a LOT faster, especially for a large number of days, but also for a large number of people.

The complexity of the naive implementation was

```
O(days * people)
```

The complexity of the preprocessed implementation is

```
O(people * log(bread) + days * log(people))
```

This doesn't sound a lot different, but it is. It basically says if the limiting factor are the people, it doesn't matter how many days, and if the limiting factor are the days, it doesn't matter how many people.

### Benchmarking Results

Setup was:

- 900 bread per day
- 10,000 people
- 10,000 days

Result:

- Naive: 2.13 seconds
- Preprocessed: 0.012 seconds

I then tried to push the algorithm so far that it also takes 2 seconds, and got those numbers:

- 90,000 bread per day
- 1,000,000 people
- 1,000,000 days

I didn't run those numbers on the naive algorithm, but the math says it would have taken about 2,000,000 seconds, or 23 days.

Well that took a while, I hope it was worth it ;)

I think this was my biggest post yet, it was a really interesting task!

I hope you appreciate it.

Greetings

Comment: thanks for this i responded on codereview. we can close this one